# Aw, Snap! screen when try to load large canvas in Mobile device using Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to load a large canvas from JSON data with a background image. On the desktop, it is loading properly. But on the mobile device, the browser crashed.

HTML code:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

I have to load and fit the entire canvas within the canvas window.

TS code:

**Prepare canvas**

```
// Calculate ratio of the canvas as per height and width
      prepareCanvas(width, height) {  // height = 3300, width = 2550
        let ratioHeight: any = Math.ceil((height / width) * 600);
        this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas("myCanvas", {
          backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
          selection: false,
          width: width <= 600 ? width : 600,
          height: width <= 600 ? height : ratioHeight
        });
        this.canvas.setDimensions(
          { width: width, height: height },
          { backstoreOnly: true }
        );
     }
```

**To load Canvas from JSON**

```
  loadTemplateFromData(canvasData: any) {        
    this.canvas.loadFromJSON(
      canvasData,
      this.canvas.renderAll.bind(this.canvas),
      (o, object) => {
        object.set("selectable", false);
      }
    );
  }
```

Using the above code the canvas loads properly in the desktop browser but crashed on the mobile browser.
One thing I have noticed if the canvas width, height are small like 300 x 300 then it is loading properly in the mobile browser. How to load a large canvas in the mobile browser?

Thanks in advance.